# Django: retrieve session or cookies in middleware

Tags: python, django, django-middleware, django-sessions

can i get the current session or cookie inside a middleware?

I tried but I got:

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'session'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work in any middleware that comes **after** `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` in settings.py.